# echo instruction in jsp

Tags: java, php, jsp, jstl

How to make "echo" (php) but in jsp?

Comment: Agreed with the person above, but it's out.print()

Comment: ok, thanx, you got the reason, but I was navigating right here, and I considered it could be an interesant question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<%="Hello Word"%>
```

Or even better

```
 <c:out value="hello World"/>
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do like this:

`out.print("whatever you want to echo");` also:

`<c:out value="${variableName}" />` where `variableNmae` would the value you want to output.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Let say we have 'some' variable:

```
String some = "Hello World";
```

Lets then print it on html as follow:

```
<%
    out.print("<h1>"+some+"</h1>");
%>
```