# Retrieve the value of a String object and place it in a value of an input

Tags: jquery, jsp

In a JSP page with a jQuery code, i want to retrieve the value of a String object and place it in the value of an input with jQuery. 
I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

The modified version

```
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="util.HibernateUtil"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#champ1').hide(); // on cache le champ par défaut

    $('select[name="couleurs"]').change(function() { // lorsqu'on change de valeur dans la liste
    var valeur = $(this).val(); // valeur sélectionnée

        if(valeur != '') { // si non vide
            if(valeur == 'jaune') { // si "jaune"
                $('#champ1').show();
<%          

            Session session4=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session4.beginTransaction();
            Query qry =  session4.createQuery("select domaine.type_domaine from Domaine domaine");

            List list = qry.list();
            String nom= (String) list.get(0);


 %>


                    $('#champ1').val(nom);


            } else {

                $('#champ1').hide();

            }
        }
    });

});
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
<p>
    <select name="couleurs">
        <option value="">-- Choisir --</option>
        <option value="vert">Option1</option>
        <option value="jaune">Option2</option>
    </select><br />

    <input type="text" name="salma" id="champ1"/>
</p>
</form>
</head>
```

Help plzz!

Comment: change to : `$("#champ1").val(nom);`

Comment: Javascript automatically add the datatype use var instead of string `var nom="jaune";`

Comment: Akash Rajbanshi, it dosen't work!!!

Comment: You need to load the HTML before the JS, as well.

Comment: Then try the answer below :D

Comment: btw, how did u get the value for the `String nom` in the jsp?

Comment: Can't you just [echo the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713013/echo-instruction-in-jsp)? `<input type="text" name="salma" id="champ1" value="put value here">`

Comment: I get it from a sql request,

Comment: can u post that code too?

Comment: so you are telling me this code `String nom="jaune";` present in jsp along with the jquery code?

Comment: I edit the my question!

Comment: Akash Rajbanshi, the code String nom="jaune" wasn't present in my first question. I just wanted to know how can i recuparate a value from a strin without posting all the code

Comment: But in fact as u can see, the String nom is the result of a sql request, that i want to display in the input using jquery

Comment: Ok..i was just wondering how you were managing your code..

Comment: Akash Rajbanshi Thank u for ur replies. I just try the code of Jonathan Anctil and it works. Thank u for ur effort.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjgv24kL/)

```
<input type="text" name="salma" id="champ1"/>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var nom = "jaune";
        $("#champ1").val(nom);
    });        
</script>
```

or try this (JSP / Javascript)

```
$('#champ1').val('<%= nom %>');
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="salma" id="champ1" value="<%= nom %>" />
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to jquery?

Comment: Haa you blend .jsp and javascript... try $('#champ1').val('<% nom %>');

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the string this way in the js:

```
 var s = "<%=nom%>";
```

Then you can add in the textfield using jquery:

```
$("#champ1").val(s);
```

Comment: Yes, that another way to do it. Thank u again!